# neo4django: AttributeError: type object 'Model' has no attribute '__metaclass__'

Tags: django-models, neo4j, neo4django

I was just trying neo4django's [very own example](https://neo4django.readthedocs.org/en/latest/writing-models.html), namely

```
from neo4django.db import models

class Person(models.NodeModel):
    name = models.StringProperty()
    age = models.IntegerProperty()

    friends = models.Relationship('self',rel_type='friends_with')
```

However, when running `python manage.py syncdb` I get the following error:

```
AttributeError: type object 'Model' has no attribute '__metaclass__'
```

Any ideas?

(I would use label "neo4django" here in Stackoverflow, but it does not let me create a new label yet).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

See https://github.com/scholrly/neo4django/issues/143- we won't support Django 1.5+ until the next release!

Comment: Yes, that was 1.5.1; I reverted to 1.4.5 for now. Thanks, Matt!