# Admin Interface setup impossible following neo4django manual

Tags: django-admin, neo4django

I am following the Neo4django manual: http://neo4django.readthedocs.org/en/latest/auth.html
and trying to setup Admin's interface. I am working under Mac OS X.

Before I started setting up this interface, I had my server running and everything worked. After I made the indicated changes, the server stopped with the error: *Error: No module named contenttypes.*
If I disable the contettypes line, I get the error  *Error: No module named admin.*

In my settings.py file:

```
INSTALLED_APPS = (
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'django.contrib.sites',
    'django.contrib.messages',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',      
    'django.contrib.admin',
    'polls',
    'mysite',
    'neo4django.admin',
    'neo4django.contenttypes',
)
```

In urls.py:

```
from django.conf.urls import patterns, include, url
from neo4django import admin

admin.autodiscover()

urlpatterns = patterns('',

    (r'^admin/', include(admin.site.urls)),
)
```

In admin.py:

```
from neo4django import admin
from .models import Person

class PersonAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    pass

admin.site.register(Person, PersonAdmin)
```

Could please someone give me correct instructions for setting up the admin's page?

Comment: Are you using the pypi version or the github version?

Comment: I installed everything from here: https://github.com/lukeorland/neo4django-tutorial/tree/3d59bae8e7dd8f33511e225247e62343b69dfef8

Comment: Oh! That explains a lot! This tutorial is a year old, for a version of neo4django that didn't had admin.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suggest you throw away the entire tutorial for the moment and install `neo4django` with `pip install -e git+https://github.com/scholrly/neo4django/#egg=neo4django`. Also check the `github` https://github.com/scholrly/neo4django and when installing `Django`, don't install the latest version but the 1.5.4 version with `pip install django==1.5.4`
Also, install the 1.9.4 version of `neo4j` and not the 2.0 version.

If for any reason you find `neo4django` a bit complicated or not mature enough then you can try the `py2neo` library (not an ORM) or `neomodel` (https://github.com/robinedwards/neomodel)

Comment: Thank you very much for the answer! I made pip install -e git+https://github.com/scholrly/neo4django/#egg=neo4django, then I installed django 1.5.4, and then in the same folder with neo4django I installed neo4j 1.8.3 (1.9.4 is not available for download on their website). Now I am trying to start a project: /Users/username/anaconda/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/bin/django-admin.py startproject myproj ; but I got errors `ImportError: Could not import settings 'mysite.settings' (Is it on sys.path?): No module named mysite.settings`.

Comment: Your problem is irrelevent to `neo4django`. You should consult the official `Django` [documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.5/intro/tutorial01/), because from what I understand you have some messed up installation of the tutorial with what I suggested. I recommend to completely delete the tutorial and create a new folder inside which you should run `django-admin.py startproject your_project_name`

Comment: It worked after I deleted the manual folder! Thank you!)) I will continue trying to set up administrator's page

Comment: Great! Remember, that the syncdb command does nothing when using neo4django.

Comment: this I understood already)) Now I cannot actually run the server, getting the error `AttributeError: type object 'Model' has no attribute '__metaclass__'`

Comment: We have already gone away from original question, so I recommecd you either search this error on StackOverflow, google it or just create correctly your models. Please take a better look on official `neo4django` (https://neo4django.readthedocs.org/en/latest/index.html) and `Django` docs

Comment: oh I have my models copied from the indicated offical `neo4django`, on which I took a very good look. But neo4django apparently does not support Django 1.5+ , as it is said here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16747310/neo4django-attributeerror-type-object-model-has-no-attribute-metaclass

Comment: I don't remember having such an issue with 1.5 version of `Django` and if you check the issue on github you will see that the issue is closed! Whatever it is, we are only one step from some SO admin, locking the question.